# clear up (v) vs. clear (v)

Tags: differences

**clear(v)** has a lot of meanings. I am only interested in this meaning:

> to remove something entirely from an area or place

**clear up** (v) has a lot of meanings. I am only interested in this meaning:

> Brit : to make an area clean or tidy

*Source: Merriam-Webster’s Advanced Learner’s English Dictionary*

So what is the difference between this two definitions? When should I prefer *clear* and when *clear up*?

What is the difference between:

- Mother ordered him to clear up his room.
- Mother ordered him to clear his room.
- It took three hours to clear the roads after the snowfall.
- It took three hours to clear up the roads after the snowfall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that the definition for 'clear' you give doesn't exactly match your example sentences. We need the definition allowing 'place to be cleared' as DO, not the subsense with 'thing/s to be removed' as DO. [CDE](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/clear) gives them both (bolding mine), though I feel the need to expand their definition in line with examples they give:

> **clear** verb ... ​ B1 [ I or T ] to remove or get rid of whatever is blocking or filling something, ***or*** to stop being blocked or full
>   [**or** to stop something being blocked or full]: ...
>
> *It took several hours to clear the road after the accident.*

The definition for 'clear up' might perhaps also be misleading. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clear%20up) certainly offers

> **clear up**  British : to make an area clean or tidy

but [Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/clear+up) anticipates how precious it would be to speak of 'making tidy' a road surface covered in rocks:

'The highly complex operation will require protecting the road surface, bringing the rock down to the road level, breaking it up and removing it and then clearing up the road surface.' [[Highland Council](https://www.highland.gov.uk/news/article/5476/potential_november_closure_of_section_of_a82)]

> **clear up**  2. to put (a place or thing that is disordered) in order

..........................

So the two verbs (one simplex, one a MWV) mean different things. They *may* essentially converge in meaning, as clearing up a place may certainly involve removing some things completely:

> The work crew soon cleared the road / cleared up the road.

However, when one *clears* a room say, he removes all removables completely:

> I need you to clear your room by noon on Friday.

Whereas when one clears up one's room say, it may just be that everything that was strewn about the room is just tidied away onto shelves anfd into drawers etc:

> You really *must* clear up your room, Toby.

Comment: Quote: "So the two verbs (one simplex, one a MWV) mean different things." What do you mean with simplex and what does MWV mean?

Comment: I subscribe to the view that a [verb + particle _or_ verb + particle + particle] construction constitutes a single lexeme. Thus 'take off' (for one sense) = 'impersonate' and 'look up to' (for the metaphorical sense) = 'respect'. Multi-word verbs consist of more than one orthographic word, unlike simplex verbs.